# Mongoose - MongoError: connection 1 to localhost:27017 timed out?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Any ideas why do I get this error below when I try to create a document?

```
Error creating the dataset: MongoError: connection 1 to localhost:27017 timed out
```

My code:

```
Dataset.create(query, function(err, dataset) {

  if (err) {
     console.log("Error creating the dataset: " + err);
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: check your mongodb conf file and find the bindIp value.

Comment: Check if db is up and running, then check db logs.